# next.js does not start to serve on port 3000

Tags: next.js

I've installed nextjs (`npx create-next-app@latest`) with TS, Tailwind, App Router and without ESlint and src.

`npm run dev` should start a dev-server on port 3000, but it quietly exits and localhost:3000 doesn't respond in my browser.

npx kill-port 3000 didn't help.

I had hoped to see the standard page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm 2 things:

1. Did you run `npm run dev` from your project root folder?
2. Do you have something else already running on port `3000`?

Comment: 1) Yes. Also tried to modify package.json to "dev = next dev -p 3333". 2) No processes are found using port 3000 (or 3333). It just waits for some seconds and then terminate without any comments.

Comment: Hmm, no error logs of any sort?